# Other ways to find line of "best" fit

Tags: regression

The most common methods I've seen to find a line of best fit are Least Squares regression and median-median. Are there other good ways? Is there a way to minimize the absolute value difference and find a line of best fit that way? Or to find the distance straight to a line instead of the vertical distance to the line? Thoughts?

Comment: Yes! Many posts on this site. One keyword to search for is L1.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'median-median' please?

Comment: An effective method for more general curve fitting (advocated by John Tukey for exploratory data analysis) that is not as well known as it should be is described and illustrated at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35711/box-cox-like-transformation-for-independent-variables/35717#35717.  A simpler version of it is to pick two "representative" points near the extremes of a scatterplot and draw the line they determine, *provided* that line appears to be a reasonable first-order description of the points in the scatterplot.

Comment: @Glen_b, "Median-median" can mean the line through [median($x$), median($y$)]
with slope = median( $y_i / x_i$ ).
This is robust and takes only a few lines of code, but is afaik hard to analyze theoretically.

Comment: @denis yes, thanks for that one -- there are a few things "median-median" could mean. My guess is the OP means something else, though it's hard to be sure. [If you know of a book or paper that discusses the one you mention, I'd be interested to take a look.]

Comment: @Glen_b, sorry, not really. There's [cran views Robust](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Robust.html) ff. -- more methods than test cases. For fun, how would you do this with $n$ predictors -- first PCA ?

Comment: @denis The reason I ask is I expect the slope calculation is done on median-centered variables, but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: @Glen_b yes, that's right, or at least how I do it -- medianline.py under [gist.github.com/denis-bz](https://gist.github.com/denis-bz) .

Answer (score 4):

Minimizing the sum of absolute differences is quite common, as Nick Cox suggests, it's often called L1 regression or Least absolute deviations regression; it's also a specific case of quantile regression and many posts here relate to it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_absolute_deviations

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression

The orthogonal distance (what I assume you mean by "straight-line distance") would correspond to a particular case of Deming regressing, itself a particular case of the total least squares line, called *orthogonal regression*, which will give the line of the first principal component.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares

There are many, many other lines that might be fitted; a couple of examples include  [Theil-Sen regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theil%E2%80%93Sen_estimator) or more generally, [robust regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_regression), which includes many different techniques.

Some discussion of robust regression (including some comparison of Theil-Sen and L1 regression) is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46229/fast-linear-regression-robust-to-outliers/).

There's some interesting discussion relating correlation measures to straight-line fits [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64938/if-linear-regression-is-related-to-pearsons-correlation-are-there-any-regressi/110112#110112)