How to test significance of Theil-Sen estimate?
I have performed a Theil-Sen slope regression on the size (hectares) of Beech trees coverage in a given Swedish forest from 1986 to 2020. The development is set to be an increase of 0.86 ha per year with my Theil-sen analysis but it does not give a significance output (p = 0.??).
I would like to test if this development is significant.
How do I get this? Some use a Mann-Kendall, is that a possibility?
Data and code in R:
years
 [1] 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016
[32] 2017 2018 2019 2020

hectares
 [1]   39.046168   45.005157   10.417670  193.189673    5.235088  354.023062  175.049482   10.497028   66.439854   25.588309    3.460545   57.713362  207.917785
[14]    9.822657   45.993183  222.602760    9.541080  205.148520   52.919640 1000.769940  241.957260    1.266840   35.808120   34.617780  199.787400   63.234900
[27]   17.435880   23.158080   36.046800    0.437580  469.456020  117.292860   55.863360  111.662460  327.166020

library(mblm)

# Calculate Theil-Sen slope and its significance
result <- mblm(hectares ~ years)
slope <- coef(result)[2]  # Extract the slope


I'm pretty sure mblm has a summary method that provides what you're looking for (if what you're looking for is a hypothesis test for your parameter being zero).

This particular dataset, which exhibits no appreciable trend (0.86/yr pales compared to year-over-year changes in the hundreds and thousands) and so it scarcely needs a test; but if you really want one, you would do just fine with ordinary least squares regression of the cube root of hectares or the log(hectares) against time.  You should find the p-value is close to 0.5.

As discussed in multiple posts on site, the usual test for a Theil-Sen slope is the test for a Kendall correlation. It should make no difference whether you use a Mann-Kendall trend or the direct test of the Theil-Sen slope; they should do the same thing; that p-value will also be pretty close to $0.5$. @whuber's suggestion of looking at a transformed response makes sense - and pretty clearly obviates the need for a test (conveniently, such transformation has no impact on that Kendall correlation). A simple loess smooth there may help as a visual aid to see there's no trend there to speak of.

Some examples of the discussion of the correspondence between Kendall correlation and Theil-Sen slope are (i) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346014/difference-between-theil-sen-estimator-and-spearman-correlation (ii) https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/110112/805 ... there are others to be found
