How to calculate the slope of a line of best fit that minimizes mean absolute error?
I have 25 data points of the form $(x,y)$ where $x$ is $1,2,3,...,25$ and $y$ is the dependent variable.
I need to determine if $y$ values are increasing, decreasing, or staying the same.
The method most commonly suggested is to fit a line to these points. If the slope is positive, $y$ is increasing, if negative, $y$ is decreasing, etc.
I've been using ordinary least squares regression to draw the line, but in some cases outliers are causing problems. I don't want to ignore the outliers, because they are relevant and important; I just don't want them to have such a huge influence. I don't want to use Theil-Sen regression, because this effectively ignores the outliers.
It seems what I want is a regression that minimizes mean absolute error or L1 error (as opposed to squared error). This kind of regression seems to be much more difficult. I've read several sources, but the calculus for general quantile regression is going over my head.
My question is this: How can I calculate the slope of the line of best fit that minimizes L1 error?
Some constraints on the answer I am looking for:

I am looking for a procedure (possibly including pseudocode, or actual code) that outputs the slope of the line.
I only need the slope of the line.
I only have 25 points, and they are 2 dimensional, so inefficient solutions that won't scale are fine, as long as they can handle this small case.


can you say more about what you mean when you say you don't want a solution implementing (sub)gradient descent? This is the simplest algo to solve this problem. I'm wondering if what you mean is you want to see an explicit algo implementing gradient descent for this specific problem, rather than someone literally just saying "do gradient descent"? Or do you feel like you need to avoid this entirely for some reason?

A gradient descent solution is fine; I just don't want the answer "use gradient descent [end of answer]"

(1) Do you really need $L^1$ regression or do you actually need some form of robust regression? (2) In The History of Statistics, Stephen Stigler describes Roger Boscovich's (1755) geometric construction.  Also see https://www.jstor.org/stable/2336819 for some further history and https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article-abstract/71/3/615/258808 for an earlier paper by Stigler on the subject.  BTW, this is not readily amenable to gradient descent, because the objective is not differentiable.

Robust regression would probably be fine as long as it's not ignoring the outliers. I want the outliers to influence the fit line, but squaring the error is causing them to have too much influence.

It's hard to determine what you would want out of an answer. Do you want an explanation of the numerical optimization of absolute loss? Do you want a derivation of a closed-form equation for the estimator the way OLS has $(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty?$ Do you just want to know a software package from which you can fit a quantile regression at the median and extract the slope?

A standard robust regression method, IRLS (aka IWLS), includes a user-settable way of penalizing extreme residuals.  It sounds like just what you might need.

@whuber sure, that sounds like it would work!

BTW, Boscovitch's ultimate solution (1760) is not quite $L^1$ regression: it minimizes the sum of absolute residuals subject to constraining the residuals to sum to zero.  This leads to a simple algorithm, because the sum-to-zero constraint causes the fitted line to pass through the point of averages.  Boscovitch argued that the slope of the solution must be a median of all the individual slopes from that point of averages to the data points.  When optimally computed with an $n$-point dataset this is an efficient $O(n\log(n))$ algorithm.

In R, IWLS is implemented by MASS::rlm. See https://rdrr.io/cran/MASS/man/rlm.html.

Is this not known as LAD regression in R: see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Blossom/versions/1.4/topics/lad

@BenP LAD and $L^1$ regression are synonymous.


Theil- Sen doesn't ignore outliers, its influence function is nondecreasing - outliers do move the median slope.  2. L1-norm regression is not robust to influential outliers.  3. A good choice will depend on how much impact you want large outliers to have for various amounts of outlyingness in x space



I said "effectively" ignores outliers for exactly that reason. At least for my data, my outliers are few enough that Theil-Sen gives the same results with and without the outliers. 3. I probably won't say this correctly, but I want outliers to have effect that is linearly proportional to their residuals (as opposed to quadratically proportional, which is what I'm getting from least squares).


Take a look at the data at the bottom of the answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/51822/805 ... where do you want the line to go? Near the red line? Near the green line? somewhere in between?

I removed some parts of the question that are off-topic. E.g., you don't need to request answers to not only give a name (that's kind of answer is against the site policy, it would probably be deleted anyways), you don't need to request that answers just point you towards a software/library (again, that type of answer is against the site policy), and you shouldn't simply ask for code (answers can have code, but answers without code are also valid)

It sounds like Bayesian Robust Linear Regression is what your looking for? Robust would mean to use a StudenT instead of a Gaussian likelihood effectively reducing the importance of outliers (without ignoring them entirely). Plus the Bayesian framework provides you with a principled way of uncertainties that you can use to make a probabilistic statement about whether or not your slope is positive. For Python, the PyMC library provides an example: https://www.pymc.io/projects/examples/en/latest/generalized_linear_models/GLM-robust.html

Here is an implementation of subgradient descent to estimate an $\ell_1$-penalized linear regression using R, which uses the fact that the subgradient of $\sum_{i=1}^N |y_i - \mathbf{x}_i^\top\beta|$ with respect to $\beta$ is given by $\mathbf{X}^\top\textrm{sign}(\mathbf{X}\beta-y) $.
## Make a cute little dataset.
N <- 25
P <- 1
X <- cbind(1,matrix(rnorm(N*P),ncol=P))
y <- 0.5*X[,1] - 0.3 * X[,2] + 1e-2*rnorm(N)

## Define cost and subgradient.
cost <- function(X,y,beta) {
    mean(abs(X%*%beta-y))
}
subgrad <- function(X,y,beta) {
    resid <- y-X%*%beta
    return(t(X) %*% (sign(-resid)) / N)
}

## Execute subgradient descent.
beta_init <- rnorm(P+1)
beta <- beta_init
step <- 5e-2
iters <- 100
for (i in 1:iters) {
    if (i%%10==0) {
        print(i)
        print(cost(X,y,beta))
    }
    beta <- beta - step*subgrad(X,y,beta)
}

## Agrees more or less with true values of 0.5, -0.3.
print(beta)


Ahh, thanks! I think I see where this is going. I'm a little confused about X (probably just confusion about R syntax). When I print X, it appears to be a matrix where the first column is always 1 and the second column is the y value?

@sgware yes except instead of y value, the second column gives your single "x" variable; it's the matrix way of representing a regression model with a single variable and an intercept. Wherever you see "X%*%beta" you can replace with "beta_0 + beta_1 * x", where beta_0 is intercept, beta_1 is slope, and x is a vector containing values of the variable.

How would I need to massage the input if these were my 25 points, given as a vector of x values and a vector of y values:
X <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25) y <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,31,2,2, 2, 2, 2,57, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)

Oh, I think I got it, but just wanted to confirm. It looks like the X matrix is random numbers (like the initial weights in a neural net) and y is the values. So: X <- cbind(1,matrix(rnorm(N*P),ncol=P)) y <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,31,2,2, 2, 2, 2,57, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)

@JohnMadden FYI: you can enclose your code with ```r and ``` to automatically highlight it for readability, as I've just done. See my edit for an example of this.

@sgware it's random numbers because I made random data; in your case, the second column of $X$ will be 1:25.

@JohnMadden I've change the data set code to this, but now it is giving much worse answers: X <- cbind(1,matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25),ncol=1)) y <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,31,2,2, 2, 2, 2,57, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2) What am I missing?

@sgware what do you mean by a worse answer?

@JohnMadden The total absolute error is higher.

Well, if I crank the number of iterations up to 1000 it is now back to giving better answers. It's odd that using randomly generated x values produced a better fit for my (non-random) x points.

@sgware yes a downside to iterative methods like GD is that you need to monitor cost vs iterations to make sure it goes down and plateaus; if it doesn't you may need to increase iteration count or decrease step size ("step" in my code).

The rq function in the quantreg package fits quantile regression models.  The default is to fit the median (tau=0.5) which is the same as minimizing the absolute values of the residuals, or l1 regression.
A quick example:
library(quantreg)
fit.l2 <- lm(y3 ~ x3, data=anscombe)
fit.l1 <- rq(y3 ~ x3, data=anscombe)
plot(y3 ~ x3, data=anscombe)
abline(fit.l2, col='red')
abline(fit.l1, col='blue')


Thanks, but my question is asking how the fit function works, not just how to call the function. This was specified in the original question, but a moderator removed it.

The help page for the quantreg::rq function gives links to several published algorithms.  As @Benno says, it's a convex optimisation problem and some of the algorithms take advantage of that. Others use the fact that it's a linear programming problem.  And there are subsampling approaches for large data

A couple of people have provided some snippets in R to achieve what you're looking for. As an alternative, here's some python code. It relies on cvxpy (a super nice library for solving convex optimisation problems).
import cvxpy
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(25)
y = 2 * x + np.random.randn(25)

beta = cvxpy.Variable(1)
intercept = cvxpy.Variable(1)
residuals = y - beta * x - intercept
objective = cvxpy.Minimize(cvxpy.norm(residuals, 1))
constraints = [cvxpy.sum_entries(residuals) == 0]
problem = cvxpy.Problem(objective, constraints)
problem.solve()
print(beta.value)

Hopefully this is pretty clear from the code but this minimises the L1 norm of the residuals subject to the constraint that the residuals sum to 0.
I think this approach is really nice because it's simple to understand, and pretty flexible (you can easily change / add / remove constraints, modify the objective, expand to additional x variables etc.)
Appendix:
convex problems are a set of optimisation problems that can be solved quickly and efficiently because they satisfy certain rules about the objective and the constraints. There exist several numerical solvers (both open source and commercial) for optimisation problems of this type, but these programs typically expect the user to specify the problem in 'canonical form'. cvxpy is basically a wrapper around these solvers allowing the user to model their optimisation problem in a more natural and flexible way - cvxpy then canonicalises the problem and passes it to a solver of your choice. If you don't want the dependency on cvxpy you could use one of these solvers directly but you'd have to write the problem in canonical form yourself.

This is close to the answer I'm looking for, and it's a nice outline of the problem, but I also want to know how the cvxpy solves the problem. The software I'm building isn't in Python, so I won't be able to rely on a library to solve the equation for me.

@sgware what language do you need it to be? I couldn't see mention of a specific language in the question or the tags. There are similar libraries to cvxpy in other programming languages e.g. cvxr for R. I'll update my answer with some more details on what cvxpy does

It's in Java, but I'd prefer not to use a library. This is less about getting it to work and more about my understanding why and how it works. Your appendix is very helpful, thank you!
